# Update native query is too slow

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, nativequery

I am using Hibernate with native query to update a field in a table with 17000 rows in Oracle.

When I execute the query on Toad, it takes 0.5s to be executed and with the below code no finish ever.

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE table SET field= LEAST(NUMERADOR/DENOMINADO, ? )");
query.setParameter(1, value);
query.executeUpdate();
```

This is the trace:

```
10-08 14:15:59 DEBUG JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [es.package.app.repository.jpa.JPAValorMaximo.update]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
10-08 14:15:59 DEBUG JpaTransactionManager - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@405264e8] for JPA transaction
10-08 14:15:59 DEBUG AbstractTransactionImpl - begin
10-08 14:15:59 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtaining JDBC connection
10-08 14:15:59 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtained JDBC connection
10-08 14:15:59 DEBUG JdbcTransaction - initial autocommit status: true
10-08 14:15:59 DEBUG JdbcTransaction - disabling autocommit
10-08 14:15:59 DEBUG JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@1bbb3b9e]
10-08 14:15:59 DEBUG SQL - UPDATE table SET field= LEAST(NUMERADOR/DENOMINADO, ? )
Hibernate: UPDATE table SET field= LEAST(NUMERADOR/DENOMINADO, ? )
```

thanks

Comment: It seems that you're not commiting the transaction 10-08 14:15:59 DEBUG JdbcTransaction - disabling autocommit

Comment: the app waits forever in the update line and doesn't continues

Comment: For such a simple update my guess is that it's waiting on some other transaction to finish.  Run a query like to this to see if the UPDATE is waiting on another session: `select * from gv$session where blocking_session is not null;`.